# I am not able to install pyfolio package using standard code

Tags: python

I am not able to install pyfolio in my local jupyter environment.

After !pip install pyfolio, the success message comes, but when I run 'import pyfolio as pf'
the following error throws.

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NaTType'

Can anyone suggest how to install pyfolio?

Comment: Ideally you'd be using `%pip install pyfolio` inside a notebook. See my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74770639/8508004) and links therein. However, you installation occurred fortunately, or you'd get "Module Not Found Error". That's not what you are seeing so your post title and question aren't addressing your issue. See [here](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/693) where someone has posted something very similar to this already. Maybe you can tag it with your experience since it looks slightly different than posted there. (Also note that is better example of a post.)

Comment: <continued> However, that main repo seems unsupported now, see [here](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/690). So it seems best to try in a **new notebook** `%pip install pyfolio-reloaded`  and then try `import pyfolio as pf`.

Answer (score 1):

The main Python Package Index (pypi) entry for pyfolio [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyfolio/) is no longer supported as described [here](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/690).

Following the suggestions there, you may want [pyfolio-reloaded](https://pypi.org/project/pyfolio-reloaded/) (repo: [here](https://github.com/stefan-jansen/pyfolio-reloaded)).
Following the directions at the repo, try running in a cell in **a new notebook** the following:

```bash
%pip install pyfolio-reloaded
```

Restart the kernel and and then try:

```bash
import pyfolio as pf
```